# Standardizing a link using a global variable in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx to document a project for work. I want to use the same link that points to a download on multiple pages throughout my documentation.

For example:
home.rst:

```
Hi
==

I want you to download_ my project.

.. _download: blah.com/download
```

other_page.rst

```
Hello Again
===========
You can also download_ it here.

.. _download: blah.com/download
```

Is there some way to have one variable that each page points to so when the link needs updated only on variable needs to be updated?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/18398548/407651

Answer (score 5):

The best option is to use a [substitution](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#substitutions), [`rst_epilog`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog), and `raw-html` as described in this [answer for mailto links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44593780/2214933).

In your `conf.py`:

```
rst_epilog = """
.. role:: raw-html(raw)
   :format: html

.. |download| replace:: :raw-html:`<a href="https://blah.com/download/">download</a>`
"""
```

In your `*.rst`:

```
Please |download| my file.
```

The [`extlink` extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html) is close, but assumes that you will want to use an URL as the base for other links to the site.

Comment: You can also just put `.. _download: blah.com/download` in `rst_epilog`.