# Sphinx / reST: Multiple anonymous explicit external links in the same paragraph

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils, external-links

How can I create two [separated external links](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets) in the same paragraph, i.e. something like:

```
for pytorch click `here <http://www.pytorch.org>`_ and for tensorflow click
`here <http://www.tensorflow.org>`_
```

that show as the following

```
for pytorch click here and for tensorflow click here
```

**BUT** with **separated** or **non-inline** links! This would allow me to gather all my external links at one place and invoke them using any caption I like.

Now, If I use **anonymous** links as in the following code:

```
.. __: pytorch_
for example.com click here__

.. __: tensorflow_
and for tensorflow.com click here__

.. _pytorch: http://www.pytorch.org
.. _tensorflow: http://www.tensorflow.org
```

This is what I get (Note separate paragraphs)

```
for pytorch click hereand for tensorflow click here
```

In other words, if we take this example ... can I use the same caption (e.g. `here`) to link to two different **explicit** and **non-inline** external links in the same paragraph?

Comment: If you had actually tried your example, you would have found it works as you desire. Please show some effort in your questions on SO.

Comment: Can you get the first result using `separated` links?

Comment: Yes, but maybe I don't understand what you are asking. Did you actually try your first example? If so, and if it was not what you wanted, please edit your question to describe what you do want. Is your question how to use multiple anonymous links with the same label in one paragraph?

Comment: basically I was trying to do `\`here <pytorch>\`_` intuitively hoping that a link called `here` will appear and then clicking it will take me to the web address. Instead it just becomes a local cross-link to `/pytorch`.

Comment: You cannot use [cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax) to achieve that end. That aside, it is poor for accessibility to hyperlink "here" or "click here". I strongly recommend instead that you hyperlink *descriptive text*, and never use "click here" in text. Touch devices do not use a mouse.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point! But you may want to change the *hyperlink descriptive text* for the same link for different contexts and the same text for different links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [extlinks](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html) extension is intended to shorten external links, but it also allows one to specify a *link description text*

To use it do the following in your `conf.py`

```py
# enable `extlinks` extension
extensions = [
        'sphinx.ext.extlinks',
]

# add external URLs
extlinks = {
        'pytorch': ('https://www.pytorch.org/%s', 'pytorch'),
        'tensorflow': ('https://www.tensorflow.org/%s', 'tensorflow')
        }
```

Now Inside the document do the following:

```
Incidentally :tensorflow:`some <>` libraries turn out to be more popular than
:pytorch:`some <>`
```

The output should look like this

```
Incidentally some libraries turn out to be more popular than some
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a substitution with raw-html role, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44593780/2214933).

Add to `conf.py`:

```
rst_epilog = """
.. role:: raw-html(raw)
   :format: html

.. |pytorch| replace:: :raw-html:`<a href="https://www.pytorch.org">here</a>`

.. |tensorflow| replace:: :raw-html:`<a href="https://www.tensorflow.org">here</a>`
"""
```

In your `.rst`:

```
|pytorch| and |tensorflow|
```

Comment: Just one thing to note. It probably will work with html builders only, and you still can't change the *description text*.